# Facebook login getting user's groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Asking this again because all info I can find only is for older api versions and not very useful.

I have a private Facebook group and am building a web app for which I'd like members to be able to access through facebook login.

That requires me to either
1. access a user's list of groups they are members of or
2. access my group's user list

I can't find any explicit documentation to do this - There seems to be a "[Groups API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/)" but very little is shared.

It requires special permissions, so I've put my app for review but it was rejected because "I need to show how this information will be used". I would only use this for filtering, so I've shared details and a video of a successful login, but seems like it was not enough.

Any idea?

Comment: So you want to limit access to your app to users who are members of your group? I don’t think there is any way any more to properly achieve that.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do. I'm very surprised at this but it seems indeed that we can't do this anymore... checked LinkedIn (as it's an alumni thing) and I can only retrieve the past 3 jobs (after going through review too) so it won't work either...